# What is the effect of 'fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF' in my source code?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am new in git. I face the following error while commit the changes.

```
**fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF**.
```

Does ignoring this warning will change my source code?

Comment: Mac/*nix use LF for line endings; Windows uses CRLF. If you're developing on Windows, it's not an issue. If you're not, it's your decision whether it matters or not. And yes, it's telling you it will change your source code by replacing LF with CRLF.